# When i require http module in node js it will not execute the program

Tags: node.js

I have the following code, whenever, I run this file with `node myserver.js`. Then the program just seems to hang or something.

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end("Hello World");
});

server.listen(8000, "localhost");
```

I'm trying to get the output on port number 8000.  But the program is not running even there is no error in the program. Maybe it's taking too much time for running. I also waited for it 10 minutes, but nothing would happen. I don't know what's going wrong here, it will just stop or just hang or something like below.
[image: my terminal]

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you're doing?  What do you mean by 'get the output on port number 8000 but program is not running..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The program is already running!!!**

The program is a Web server running on port `8000` which returns `Hello World` whenever a request is received.

You can validate this by running the program, opening up Chrome (or any browser, Postman etc), and then hitting url `http://localhost:8000`

You can also add a callback to the `server.listen()` method which lets you know that the server is now listening.

Like

```js
server.listen(8080, "localhost", () => {
  console.log("Server started on 8080");
})
```

Note that, this is not required and is just a confirmation for you to know that the server is running.

**P.S.** - The `localhost` argument to `server.listen` is not really required. Since it is taken by default

Comment: If you want to make this message stand out, (in case you have more logs for debugging etc) you can add color (and [CSS in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)) to it like this `console.log('%c Server started on 8080', 'color: #green')`.